# Select * from table where id = ? and order by priority

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a database with those fields:

- id (int)
- name (text)
- priority (int)

I want to show values from database where id = (e.g) 13 and sort them by priority.
E.G: The field with id 13 and priority 1 will be first from the other field with priority 2.

How can i do it?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id >= 13 ORDER BY priority ASC` Seriously? couldn't research this much?

Comment: well.. the `id >= 13` it's not the `where` that the OP need :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,name,priority from table_name WHERE id=13 ORDER BY priority ASC;
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly say `priority ASC` cause `asc` is the default order.

Comment: Yes True. Its for the Questioner's understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`priority` FROM table_name WHERE `id`=13 ORDER BY `priority` ASC;
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly say `priority ASC` cause `asc` is the default order.

Comment: sure, but does not affect the code, the OP can remove it if prefeer

Comment: This is perfect, i answer before the @chandran, he answered the same of me.. the OP mark his answer how the best answer and for me one negative.. somebody can explains me?

Comment: No idea, who have down voted cause I generally don't cast -1 rather provide comment if something is wrong. Again your answer is valid and +1 from my side for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering can be managed with the field function:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`priority` FROM table_name 
order by FIELD(priority,"13","2")
```

Watch out for practical issues: YOu have to manually maintain this order list (or create some structure to maintain this).

Comment: it's bad idea to order with a `FIELD(priority, 13, 2)`, The OP only need a `ORDER BY priority ASC;`

Comment: The query will return all the values not just id=13